# ComVisible() vs ComVisibleAttribute()

Tags: c#, attributes, comvisible

Whats the difference between using `[ComVisible()]` and `[ComVisibleAttribute()]` ? They do exactly the same thing so whats the difference?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common convention in .NET is to end all attribute classes with the suffix `Attribute` - so the actual class name is `ComVisibleAttribute`. This fits the best practices for extending a class and keeping its name as a suffix.

However, this makes attribute names long and unwieldy, and clutters your code with a lot of boilerplate words. That's why the C# compiler know that when an attribute is specified, it searches both for the explicit name given, and if it isn't found, it will append `Attribute` to it.

If you check the compiled source for your code, you'll see that both `[ComVisible]` and `[ComVisibleAttribute]` compile to *exactly* the same thing. It's just the compiler giving us some syntactic sugar to avoid seeing the word Attribute everywhere.